# what is the difference between the total= df.isnull().sum(), percent1= df.count(),percent= df.isnull().count()?

Tags: pandas

Can anyone tell difference between the total= df.isnull().sum(), percent1= df.count(), df.isnull().count()  as Ideally df.isnull().count() should give all the count of only null values but it is giving count of all the values .Can anyone help me to understand this?

Below is the code where i am getting output of variable total as only null values count and percent1 as only not null values count and percent as count of all the values irrespective of null or not null.

```
total= df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
percent1= df.count()#helps to get all the non null values count
percent= df.isnull().count()
print(total)
print(percent1)
print(percent)
```

Comment: This is a pure `pandas` question, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `artificial-intelligence` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed)

Comment: ok I will take care of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of [count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) according to the doc is:

*Count non-NA cells for each column or row.*

And using `isnull` (or `isna`) change your dataframe `df` of whatever types you have in it to a boolean dataframe, with `True` where nan is originally `df` and False otherwise, there is no more `nan` in this dataframe, so `count` on `df.isnull()` will return the number of row of `df` as no nan exist in it. With an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(4), 'b':[1,np.nan, 3, np.nan]})
print (df)
   a    b
0  0  1.0
1  1  NaN
2  2  3.0
3  3  NaN
```

if you use `count` on this dataframe you get:

```
print (df.count())
a    4
b    2 # here you get 2 because you have 2 nan in the column b as defined above
dtype: int64
```

but if you use `isnull` on it you get

```
print (df.isnull())
       a      b
0  False  False
1  False   True #was nan in column b in df
2  False  False
3  False   True
```

Here you don't have `nan` anymore, so the result of `count` will be the number of rows for both columns

```
print (df.isnull().count())
a    4
b    4 #no more nan in df.isnull()
dtype: int64
```

But because `True` is actually equal to 1 and `False` equal to 0, then using the `sum` method will add one for each `True` in `df.isnull()`, meaning of `nan` originally in `df`

```
print (df.isnull().sum())
a    0 # because only False in column a of df.isnull()
b    2 # because you have two True in df.isnull() in column b
dtype: int64
```

Finally, you can see the relation like this:

```
(df.count()+df.isnull().sum())==df.isnull().count()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it .. Thanks for such an good explanation